An error occurred while clearing the cache. Probably not all caches were deleted as expected
I have installed TYPO3 version 12.4.19 at Mittwald. Right after the installation, when I hadn't added anything else to TYPO3, such as plugins, etc., and I click on the lightning bolt icon to clear all caches, I receive the following error message: "An error occurred. An error occurred while clearing the cache. Probably not all caches were deleted as expected."
I am unsure what to do because the cache is not being cleared this way, which means I cannot work on the site. I am aware that I can clear the cache via the Install Tool, and that works, but for clients who want to make changes on the site, this method is no longer viable.
Could you please assist me?

Check the PHP error log there must be an error that prevent the cache from being cleared.

There is nothing in the error log. On my phone it works by clearing the cache. I've already tried a different network on my PC and all the browsers available and it still doesn't work.

You need to check the error logs to find out what specific error occurred. And this should give you a hint what wrong.
Maybe certain cache tables do not exist or a cache backend is misconfigurerd.
Bur without the error detail no one will be able to help you

There is nothing in the error log..

When I updated from 11.5 to 12.4, similar things occurred: cache clearing not possible, upgrade wizard and database compare the same, but no hint in the error logs. BUT: I have a sitepackage extension, which have had unsuitable things in it, please see
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/BestPractises/ConfigurationFiles.html

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
